# Can't properly unistall and reinstall .NET

Tags: .net-framework

I just got redirected here from stackoverflow, so I'll be brief: I'm trying to run a mod for a game, and wiki page says I need to completely unistall .NET and reinstall it in order (4.5, then 4.7 then 4.7.2). Problems:

1) can't unistall whatever .net I have (4.6.2 - neither through control panel nor through something I found: "dotnetfx_cleanup_tool")

2) can't install anything below 4.6.2 (it says it's already installed)

3) can't install anything above 4.6.2 (it's says it's "not supported")

How can I solve this? Do I need some specific upgrade for W10 to install .net 4.7?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to run a mod for a game, and wiki page says I need to completely unistall .NET and reinstall it in order (4.5, then 4.7 then 4.7.2).

.NET 4.5 cannot be installed on Windows 10 since you already have .NET 4.7.2 installed.  .NET Framework 4.7.2 replaces all versions between 4.0 and 4.7.1.

> can't unistall whatever .net I have (4.6.2 - neither through control panel nor through something I found: "dotnetfx_cleanup_tool")

This is by design.

> can't install anything below 4.6.2 (it says it's already installed)

It is installed.  .NET Framework 4.7.2 replaces .NET Framework 4.6.2.

> can't install anything above 4.6.2 (it's says it's "not supported")

Since you are running 1803, the stand-alone .NET Framework 4.6.2 installer is not applicable to your installation.

> Do I need some specific upgrade for W10 to install .net 4.7?

You already have it installed.

> wiki page says I need to completely unistall .NET

These instructions are only applicable to Windows 7.  They are also not even valid since, no matter what version of Windows you are running. .NET Framework 4.7.2 replaces 4.0 through 4.6.2.

Comment: If by some strange coincidence you are not running 1803, upgrade to it, this will insure that your .NET Framework installation is also upgraded.  Of course make all appropriate and applicable backups before you do that.  Please do not ask additional questions in a comment to this answer.